# get value of link in js

Tags: javascript, android, href

im working on android HTML5 app and i have this problem i hope it's easy for you to solve

i have this JS code and it's working fine

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
var myTable = '' ;

var url = "categories.php";

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
           i=1;
                $.each(json, function(k, v) {

                myTable +=   "<li><a href='"+v.link_title+"'>"+v.title+"</a></li>";

                });
                $("#cats").html(myTable) ;

        });
  });
```

This Code Output is :

```
<li><a href='1'>CatrgoryA</a></li>
```

href (1) is the ID of this category

Now What i want to do is:

1. When user click on this link, it takes him to the CatrgoryA Page and Display all results Under this category.

the result is not the problem, 
the problem is HOW DO I MAKE JS GET THE VALUE OF THE CATEGORY SO I CAN GET RESULTS

Comment: Are you trying to get the href attribute of "1", or are you trying to get the anchor text "CategoryA"?

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Everyone i have solve it using this method:

```
var parts = window.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
var $_GET = {};
for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    var temp = parts[i].split("=");
    $_GET[decodeURIComponent(temp[0])] = decodeURIComponent(temp[1]);
}

alert($_GET['cat']);
```

The Link is:

```
category.html?cat=1
```

and Now when i run it, 
it alert me with the number 1 
that's Exactly what i want...

Thank You, 
@Rich

Answer (score 0):

You are not including any key to your categories on that link. You could use a data attribute to store that (probably you have the key on that JSon's collection from which you're rendering the anchors).

So, if I'm correct on my assumptions, you need to store the key on the anchor and you could do it by using:

```
 myTable += "<li><a href='"+v.link_title+"' data-key='"+v.wahtever_the_key_name_is+"'>"+v.title+"</a></li>";
```

With that, you could access this key value using the JQuery `attr()` method, like this:
    $('a').attr('data-key');

But you have another issue: you're not calling the result page by yourself, you're receiving the link from the JSon collection. In that case, it all depends on how this link is being received. You could use, for instance:

```
 myTable += "<li><a href='"+v.link_title+"?key="+v.wahtever_the_key_name_is"' data-key='"+v.wahtever_the_key_name_is+"'>"+v.title+"</a></li>";
```

And in that case you would be informing the selected category on the request it-self (on the `?key=` part), assuming that you do know how to get this on your backend.

Is this it?

Comment: Thank You @Marcelo Myara what you are saying is Completely True but i have found easier way to done that By Using this Here,

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19192920/1796928